# Identify what type of database object is in django

Tags: python, django

I have a function where I pass an object from the `Car` column or an object from the `Plane` column.

In this function, I'd like to do slightly different things depending on what column it came from. Essentially, I'd like to say something like

```
if object.is_car:
    # do something
elif object.is_plane:
    # do something else
```

What's the best way to do this? I'm sure it's simple and I'm missing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`isinstance()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#isinstance)

Comment: this is true, but in many cases the better approach is to encapsulate differences in the "vehicle" objects and take advantage of duck typing to remove the need for the special case in code that uses the objects